# void vs Mono<Void> in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I recently started working on Spring Webflux application using reactive streams. I have 2 questions.

1. What is the difference between `void` and `Mono<Void>`
2. I have a usecase like the following where I think could be improved using `void` or `Mono<Void>`

   ```
    @Service
    public class ABCService {  
      public Mono<String> getGreeting(String name) {
        Mono.just(NameValidator.validate(name))
             .map(isValid -> "Hello, "+name+". Welcome!");
      }

    }

    public class NameValidator {

      public static boolean validate(String name) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {throw new RuntimeException("Invalid name");}
        return true;

     }

    }
   ```

I dont actually need the validate() method to have a **boolean** return type. It could be `void/Mono<Void>` instead. I only return `true` to performing chaining in the ABCService. Can someone explain how to do the same using `void` and `Mono<Void>`

Comment: `Mono.fromRunnable(() -> NameValidator.validate(name)).thenReturn("Hello, "+name+". Welcome!")` - this would be the idiomatic way to execute this

Comment: What if I want to use the validator in middle of a reactive pipeline? Something like this, 

`Mono.just(name)
.map(n -> n.toUpperCase())
.map(name -> {    NameValidator.validate(name);    return name; })
.map(name -> "Hello, "+name+ ". Welcome!");`

I know this is a contrived example but I have a similar usecase

Comment: I would use it inside a doOnNext rather than a map.

Comment: 2 questions I have, 
1. When would like doOnNext() be called? 
2. Does it depend on where I place it? Will it act differently if I place the doOnNext() as the last method() VS if I use in in between those map? What if I want it to be called in the exact place where I'm doing the validation i.e., after 2 map in the above example.

Comment: The operators are executed in declaration order, so its place matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return Mono you can't use `map()`. I mean you can use it, but since `Mono<Void>` will never emit a value but only a completion signal, your `map()` will never take effect. You would need to replace it with `then()`:

```java
@Service
public class ABCService {  
  public Mono<String> getGreeting(String name) {
      NameValidator.validate(name)
         .then(Mono.just("Hello, "+name+". Welcome!"));
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use the validator to an already existing reactive chain? Something like this, 

`Mono.just(name).map(n -> n.toUpperCase()).map(name -> {
   NameValidator.validate(name);
   return name;
}).map(name -> "Hello, "+name+ ". Welcome!");`

Comment: That would also work, but to be honest that could be a lot simpler. You don’t really need the Mono from begining to end. There is no purpose on creating a Mono just for the sake of creating it unless you can take any advantage doing so. In you example I doubt it is helpfull.

Comment: I'm new to webflux. Can you suggest/show the actual way to do the above example in my comment (`Mono.just(name).map(n -> n.toUpperCase()).....`) The example is a bit contrived but I have a similar thing I did in my work where I don't get the `name` at the bottom of the pipeline but rather a object which was derived from another object above it.

Comment: What do you want to do with name before validating it? Convert it to uppercase only? Is name a simple String (not Mono of String)?

Comment: For simplicity, lets assume I'm only converting to uppercase before validating it. It could be some other thing as well rather than `toUpperCase()` a different method, that has to be performed for sure. Yeah, `name` is a string. `Mono.just()` will give us a `Mono<String>`.

Comment: Do you really need your service to return a Mono? It receives a String and it seems that none of the operations you want to apply require a Mono to be used. I am asking all these things so that I can understand better your use case.

Comment: My actual usecase is something similar but instead of `String` we use custom class objects instead. It could technically be done in a normal way but we are using webclient which creates the 1st Mono, and to chain those back to the user through controller, we created an entire chain of operators similar to what I have above. Because if there is a mono being without block we will only have to use chain of operators, right. Note: We are not using complete reactive, we are willing to have a reactive pipeline that gives output as application/json not as a stream.

Comment: But even if you are using WebClient you don’t need to use Mono from the beginning. If your Validator and Operators that you want to apply to the String don’t require a Mono as a parameter then don’t use it. Only after the first operation requiring Mono (in your case I admit that it is the WebClient call) you need to handle Monos. If your Controller endpoint returns Mono, it will still respond as JSON.

Comment: I want to validate the response I get back from the webclient. That's the validation usecase I have

Comment: Please create a new question on which you detail your use case including your code so that we can really understand what you need. Then add here as a comment the link to it so that I can also check it. Thank!